# django- how to address static files in 404.html template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-extensions

according to django's documentation:

> When you raise Http404 from within a view, Django loads a special view devoted to handling 404 errors. By default, it’s the view django.views.defaults.page_not_found(), which either produces a very simple “Not Found” message or loads and renders the template 404.html if you created it in your root template directory.

, i created a 404.html file in the root template directory.
when the app raises a 404 error, this 404.html that i created before, will shown, but it's css and it's background image not load.

this is the 404.html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>not found</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/error_style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body class="color-404">
<div id="error">
    <img class="error-image" src="{% static 'img/404.jpg' %}"/>
</div>
<div class="error-router">
    <a href="#" class="gohome"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    <a href="" onclick="window.history.back();" class="goback"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i fix this problem?
tanx

Comment: What does `{% static 'css/error_style.css' %}` render as?

Comment: @alasdair this is for serving page style.
is it wrong?

Comment: I mean, what does it look like in the rendered 404.html template? Click view source in your browser to check.

Comment: @alasdair <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/error_style.css"/> 
and this css is really exists.<br>
excuse me sir, my English is not enough good!

Comment: Your 404.html template looks ok - it sounds like the problem is with your [static files config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/).

Comment: @alasdair when i set DEBUG to False in settings.py file of my project, anyone of my static files not load in all pages. what's the problem sir?

Comment: I found it. this problem is because of DEBUG = False. 
and i found how to solve it.

Comment: Django doesn't serve static files when debug is False. You need to configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve them.  See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#deployment) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem.
because i set DEBUG to False, django's built-in webserver, was not served staticfiles.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but in general it is best to not have external .js and .css files in error-pages.
Include it in the page itself, to avoid situations like this, where for some reason the error-page produces an error. Use a single static page.